# Dynamically setting meta tag using DocHead in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am dynamically setting `<meta>` tag in my `<head>` for Twitter card. The following sets the meta tag when I inspect the `<head>` on my Chrome:

```
  FlowRouter.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    action() {
      let title = 'my app';
      DocHead.setTitle(title);

      DocHead.removeDocHeadAddedTags();
      DocHead.addMeta({name: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary'});
      DocHead.addMeta({name: 'twitter:site', content: '@myapp'});
      DocHead.addMeta({name: 'twitter:title', content: 'my app title'});
      DocHead.addMeta({name: 'twitter:description', content: 'my app desc'});
      DocHead.addMeta({name: 'twitter:image', content: 'logourl'});

      mount(MainLayoutCtx, {
        content: () => (<Home />)
      });
    }
  });
```

But when I debug it using tools such as [social debug](http://socialdebug.com/), I always get that no meta tag was found for Twitter. What gives? I am using `spiderable` in my app. This also happens on production.

Comment: *"What gives?"* If their scraper only works from html source then modifying it with javascript will be after they have read the source. Similar to older days when search engines didn't read asynchronously loaded html ... not really sure that all even do these days yet and even though google does...their results are still not perfect

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for pointing to the right direction. Resolved by implementing server side rendering.

Comment: @charlietfl Please add your comment as an answer and I will accept it.